# Must declare the scalar variable "@Emp_ID"

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
   con.Open();
    //stringquery=("insert into Tbl_EmployeeDetails values='"+txtName.Text+"','"+txtContact.Text+"','"+txtAddress.Text+"','"+txtEmployeeID.Text+"','"+txtJobLocation.Text+"','"+txtDateOfBirth.Text+"','"+Rdllist.selectedItem.Text+"'");
    //sql command cmd=new sqlcommand(query,con);
    //cmd.ExecuteNonquery();
    SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("Insert into Tbl_EmployeeDetails(Name,Address,Contact,Emp_ID,JobLocation,DateOfBirth,Gender)values(@Name,@Address,@Contact,@Emp_ID,@JobLocation,@DateOfBirth,@Gender)",con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", txtContact.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee_ID", txtEmp_ID.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobLocation", txtJobLocation.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", txtDateOfBirth.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Rdllist.SelectedItem.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,this.GetType(),"alertMessage","alert('Record Inserted Successfully')",true);
        txtName.Text= String.Empty;
        txtAddress.Text= String.Empty;
        txtContact.Text= String.Empty;
        txtEmp_ID.Text= String.Empty;
        txtJobLocation.Text= String.Empty;
        txtDateOfBirth.Text= String.Empty;
       // txtGender.Text= String.Empty;

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please before to ask your question, please read "how do I ask a good question" : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [You have to Refer this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37983859/error-converting-datatype-nvarchar-to-int-from-c-sharp-to-sql/37984040#37984040)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

> @Employee_ID should be @Emp_ID the same as it is with your query.

eg:

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp_ID", txtEmp_ID.Text);`

**Hence try this:**

```
  con.Open();

     SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("Insert into Tbl_EmployeeDetails(Name,Address,Contact,Emp_ID,JobLocation,DateOfBirth,Gender)values(@Name,@Address,@Contact,@Emp_ID,@JobLocation,@DateOfBirth,@Gender)",con);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", txtContact.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp_ID", txtEmp_ID.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobLocation", txtJobLocation.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", txtDateOfBirth.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Rdllist.SelectedItem.Text);

       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,this.GetType(),"alertMessage","alert('Record Inserted Successfully')",true);
    txtName.Text= String.Empty;
    txtAddress.Text= String.Empty;
    txtContact.Text= String.Empty;
    txtEmp_ID.Text= String.Empty;
    txtJobLocation.Text= String.Empty;
    txtDateOfBirth.Text= String.Empty;
   // txtGender.Text= String.Empty;

    con.Close();
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just change your values to:

```
values(@Name,@Address,@Contact,@Employee_ID,@JobLocation,@DateOfBirth,@Gender)
```

Since you called it like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee_ID", txtEmp_ID.Text);
```

or

```
 values(@Name,@Address,@Contact,@Emp_ID,@JobLocation,@DateOfBirth,@Gender)

 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp_ID", txtEmp_ID.Text);
```

> Whatever the name in values is going to be used in cmd.parameters.addwithvalue.

Beware of the pitfalls of AddWithValue: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/